# Linking backlog to feature in tfs 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm working with TFS 2015. 
The thing is that my team has got a Feature. Inside this feature we have several backlogs. My teammate is working on backlog X. His backlog shows on the task board.
How to do this ? I can only add tasks from feature view.

[Features page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuH7k.png)

[Task board page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smrOt.png)

Should I add a new backlog in the task board view and then link this feature as parent? But how exactly should it look? I need instructions step by step.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will have similar question in the future:

You have to change iteration path in the backlog to have it shown on the task board.